# Clojure tools.logging not logging stacktrace

Tags: clojure

In the latest version (0.2.4) of [tools.logging](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging), when logging with (error some-exception), only the exception message is logged. I depend on having the stack trace printed when an exception is logged. Printing the exception to stderr or stdout is not an option.

As far as I can see in the [source](https://github.com/clojure/tools.logging/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/logging.clj), (error ...) does take an exception as the first argument.

```
 (log/error throwable error-message)
```

What can I do to include the stack traces when logging?

Answer (score 3):

The signature of error is:

```
(defmacro error
  "Error level logging using print-style args."
  {:arglists '([message & more] [throwable message & more])}
  [& args]
  `(logp :error ~@args))
```

which means that with just 1 param (as in `(error some-exception)`), the parameter is the message (which in your case is the `toString` of some-exception).

If you want to log the stacktrace you need a second param message like:

```
(def ex (RuntimeException. "ex"))
(error ex "Something broke!")
```

or

```
(error ex ex)
```

Comment: (error ex "some-message") is what I tried. It does not print the stack trace.

Comment: Hi Odinodin, it works for me. I just realized that you claim you are using version 0.2.5, but that version doesn't exist yet. The latest released version is 0.2.4.